# Send Email when Azure CI Pipeline Just Started Running

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I know there is an option to send an email when Azure CI pipeline completes/failed, but what I'm looking for is an option when a particular pipeline has just started/upon running, is there such thing? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT not exactly, its just one of our db team was asking if theres an option for it, i told him there are extensions like the answers below, but he prefers an option directly under settings in azuredevops, but since it doesnt exist so he stops asking, it would be great if you guys the dev can add that option, thanks

Comment: Hi, You could add this request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Comment: By the way, do you mind accepting the workaround as the answer? It could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure DevOps does not have this notification, we could install the extension [Send Email](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask&ssr=false#overview), and use the task `Send email` to get the email notification that the pipeline has just run.

We could also refer to this [doc](https://github.com/TotalALM/VSTS-Tasks/tree/master/Tasks/Email) to use email task to send email.

**Note**: We could not send email for a azure DevOps team group via these tasks

Comment: I dont know if you work for MSFT or not but if you do could you add that feature natively?

Answer (score 2):

Check this extension: [CatLight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=catlight.catlight&ssr=false#overview). It does not send emails just popups in your tray.